# Can someone tell me which version of Angular is this code using?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, model-view-controller, razor

could you help me with this?

So lately I've been tasked to continue an app development project using Angular and ASP.NET. I'm new to both Angular and ASP.NET so first I decided to take a look through Angular's website (https://angular.io)

But when I see the documentation, I couldn't find anything that is -- at least -- similar to the code this app were using. In `.cshtml` file, Angular always begin with the following model:

```
    Html.Angular()
```

which later being varies based on their respective needs, such as

```
    Html.Angular().PicklistFor("vm.choosenOption")
                  .Title("OptionID")
                  .Id("name")
```

I've been looking for an answer to this quite awhile through Google, but to no result. Can anyone point me which version of Angular is this and where to look?

Comment: I'd click on "Angular" and press F12 (or right-click it and select "Go to definition"). Chances are it's an extension method (C#) that was created for your project.

Comment: You can check for package.json to see the version of angular. If it uses some package wrapper like bower you should check it in bower.json. If it uses angular-cli with sure it is an angular version >=2.

Comment: That is most certainly HtmlHelper extensions to generate AngularJS (Angular 1). Your best bet would be to use your IDE to the definition of that Angular() call. It could even be internal functions written by someone else in your company.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! It is indeed an extension called AngularHelper. But is there any online documentation to this?

Comment: As @John has mentioned, it's most likely something homebrewed. Another option is to search through the NuGet Package Manager and see if AngularHelper was part of some external code.

Comment: If it's not defined in one of your files, then at the very top of the "definition" file should be a comment with the assembly name that it appears in.

Answer (score 0):

Analyse the Package.json file in your project and check the reference of packages.